# How to write a test class for Schedulable class?

Tags: unit-test

```
global with sharing class Batchaccountcountfieldschedule implements Schedulable 
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)    
    {
       Batchaccountcountfield bb = new Batchaccountcountfield();
       database.executebatch(bb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you test class schedule your class

```
Test.startTest();
Batchaccountcountfieldschedule sh1 = new Batchaccountcountfieldschedule();
String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?'; 
system.schedule('Test Territory Check', sch, sh1); 
Test.stopTest();
// add system asserts to check your expected behaviour
```

Comment: @Bonny Cool It helped you

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but IMO this is not a test class. This is a 'coverage class'. All it gives you is code coverage to hit the 75% code coverage mark, but it does not test any behaviour. In order for this to be a good test, it needs to make some assertions about the code that's run. In this case, the test should ensure that the batch has run successfully.

Comment: Perhaps we should. If someone asks me how to do things the wrong way, I won't give him an answer. I rather explain how to do things the right way. You're not doing anybody a favour if you help them do things wrong. But that's a different discussion altogether :)